# Jackson deserializing json choosen fields

Tags: java, jackson

there is possibility to deserialize Json only choosen fields?
Eg:

```
{
    "Version": 1,
    "Key": "353301_PC",
    "Type": "PostalCode",
    "Rank": 500,
    "LocalizedName": "Kleosin",
    "EnglishName": "Kleosin",
    "PrimaryPostalCode": "16-001",
    "Region": {
      "ID": "EUR",
      "LocalizedName": "Europe",
      "EnglishName": "Europe"
    }
```

And i want only LocalizedName and EnglishName. Tried with objectMapper but getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JsonIgnoreProperties annotation to your data class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class YourClass {

   private String LocalizedName;

   private String EnglishName;
   
   ...
}
```

Comment: You can also put it on a global level: objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Comment: It work i guess, but now i am getting null :( all names are good, will edit main post with json and classes;

Answer (score 0):

you can add @JsonIgnore to the fields inside the Region class